# Set in dynamic query value of variable declared outside dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which i simplified this way :

```
DECLARE @variable1 INT

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
    DECLARE @variable2 INT

    SET @variable2 = 1
    SET '+CAST(@variable1 AS VARCHAR)+' = @variable2

    SELECT @variable1 as V1, @variable2 as V2
'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

But this script don't give me anything ! I'm pretty sure it's something related to scope. The thing is that i need to declare the variable outside the dynamic query.

thanks for help !

EDIT :

```
WHILE LOOP UNTIL SELECT COUNT xxx = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @variable1 INT

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = '
                EXEC STORE PROC WITH PARAMETER @Param1 = @variable1 (first loop @Param1 is null)

                STORE PROC RETURN A VALUE

                SET @variable1 with return value of store proc
                and use it in second loop, third loop...
    '
    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Comment: Your `@variable1` is null in this script; so, this : `SET '+CAST(@variable1 AS VARCHAR)+`... will be null ; ps: CAST(AS VARCHAR) should be always `CAST(AS VARCHAR(XX))`

Comment: ok but is there a way to go over that ?

Comment: you should provide more details; you could initialize it with a value  : `DECLARE @variable1 INT =0`

Comment: you mean initialize the value inside the dynamic query or outside ? i will try to edit my question to provide more details !

Comment: @MatthieuRGX  A `NULL` value will always return `NULL` even if you add stuff to it. Consider this Select: `SELECT NULL + 'String'`. It returns `NULL` and the `'String'` is removed. In your first example, you are essentially doing `SET @SQL = NULL`

Comment: use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec()`

Comment: i've edit my question !

Comment: What the point in using a dynamic query this case?

Comment: because there is some variable that change and i think i can't do it whitout dynamic query ! The stored proc i call inside the dynamic query is in multiple server so i need to use dynamic query to call the right server when i need it !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three things worth mentioning:

- Always use `PRINT` to view the resulting dynamic SQL whenever you work with dynamic SQL. You will see that the SQL variable is actually holding `NULL`.

  ```
  DECLARE @variable1 INT

  DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

  SET @SQL = '
      DECLARE @variable2 INT

      SET @variable2 = 1
      SET ' + CAST(@variable1 AS VARCHAR) + ' = @variable2

      SELECT @variable1 as V1, @variable2 as V2
  '

  PRINT(@SQL)

  -- EXEC(@SQL)
  ```

[image]

- The reason because the dynamic SQL is `NULL` is because you are concatenating a NULL value which is the `@variable1` contents. I believe you wanted to write down the text `'@variable1'` as literal:

  ```
  DECLARE @variable1 INT

  DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

  SET @SQL = '
      DECLARE @variable2 INT

      SET @variable2 = 1
      SET @variable1 = @variable2

      SELECT @variable1 as V1, @variable2 as V2
  '

  PRINT(@SQL)
  ```

[image]

- Whenever you use EXEC, the scope changes and variables declared outside can't be accessed anymore. So inside the dynamic SQL, you won't be able to read `@variable1` since it's not declare anywhere. If we execute the dynamic SQL:

[image]

---

The way you can set variables values inside a dynamic execution and be able to read them from the outside is by supplying parameters via the `OUTPUT` option. This will require to use the SP [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) rathen than a direct `EXEC`:

```
DECLARE @externalVariable INT

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
    DECLARE @variable2 INT = 1
    SET @resultVariable = @variable2'

EXEC sp_executesql
    @stmt = @SQL,
    @params = N'@resultVariable INT OUTPUT',    -- Declare the "input" parameters for the dynamic SQL
    @resultVariable = @externalVariable OUTPUT  -- Supply the "input" parameters for the dynamic SQL

SELECT 
    Result = @externalVariable -- Read the updated value
```

Note that I changed data types to `NVARCHAR` since `sp_executesql` works with unicode inputs.

Another example with more parameters:

```
DECLARE @firstNumber INT = 15
DECLARE @secondNumber INT = 3
DECLARE @result INT

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SET @multiplicationResult = @inputFactor1 * @inputFactor2'

EXEC sp_executesql
    @stmt = @SQL,
    @params = N'
        @multiplicationResult INT OUTPUT,
        @inputFactor1 INT,
        @inputFactor2 INT',
    @multiplicationResult = @result OUTPUT,
    @inputFactor1 = @firstNumber,
    @inputFactor2 = @secondNumber

SELECT 
    Result = @result -- 45!
```

If you don't have to read back results from variables, you can build your dynamic SQL by "hard-coding" the variables values directly into the script. Make sure to correctly use data type conversions inside the script and also escape `NULL` and literal values:

```
DECLARE @DateVariable DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @StringVariable VARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @FloatVariable FLOAT = 15.14

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT
        DateVariableContents = CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @DateVariable), '') + '''),
        StringVariableContents = ' + ISNULL('''' + @StringVariable + '''', '''''') + ',
        FloatVariableContents = CONVERT(FLOAT, ''' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @FloatVariable), '') + ''') '

PRINT(@DynamicSQL)

EXEC(@DynamicSQL)
```

Printed:

```
SELECT
    DateVariableContents = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Mar 21 2019  3:27PM'),
    StringVariableContents = '',
    FloatVariableContents = CONVERT(FLOAT, '15.124')
```

Result:

```
DateVariableContents        StringVariableContents  FloatVariableContents
2019-03-21 15:28:00.000                             15.124
```

Answer (score -2):

try this query

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @a int
set @a = 1

WHILE @a < 6 
BEGIN
SET @SQL = '
    DECLARE @variable ' + cast(@a as varchar)  + ' INT '
PRINT(@SQL)
    SET @a = @a + 1 
END 

PRINT(@SQL)
```

Comment: Pmease enhance your answer by explaining what the query does.